# Moodle database - user permissions

Tags: mysql, moodle

Where in moodle 2.6.1 database (mysql) i can find info about user permissions ? 
When user creates account he has permission (logged user), how to change via database that permission to student ?

Thanks for help , best regards

Answer (score 1):

Oh the capabilities are complex.

I wouldn't change it via SQL - use the site admin instead to change permissions

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Override_permissions

Comment: Thank you for answer , Is there any way to change it via sql ? I really need it to do it automatically without human clicking.

Comment: Maybe create a role with the permissions you want and then assign the user to that role?

Comment: I want to do something loke that to give permission like student or put him to group to allow to see course. I want to do it after payment action or write special password. That have to be via sql or cron, is this even possible ?

Comment: There is a paypal enrolment plugin - maybe have a look at the code for that, see if it does want you want - http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Paypal_enrolment

Comment: I can see that in paypal settings when user pay it's changing his role to student so this is possible i think